# Laravel 5.4 One to Many relationship (check if record exist in pivot table)

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I want to check if current user already has this car.

**User.php:**

```
public function car()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Car::class);
    }
```

**Car.php**

```
public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

For example, I'm passing to view all cars from cars table and I want to check if current user already has this car:

```
@foreach( $cars as $car )

   @if(Auth::user()->cars->where('car_id', $car->id)->exists())

        You have this car!

   @else

        Buy this car!

   @endif

@endforeach
```

Now, this code returns an error:

> Call to a member function where() on null

How can I check if User already has this car?

Comment: you have `public function car()` so it should be `Auth::user()->car()->where('car_id', $car->id)->exists()`, see [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) example from Laravel 5.4 docs.

Comment: @makadev Thanks, man!!!

Comment: @makadev can you write your answer so I can close this question?

Comment: added as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 Problems:

First the typo `car`/`cars`.

Second, you have `public function car()` so it should be `Auth::user()->car()->where('car_id', $car->id)->exists()` for condition chaining.

Check out the ["One To Many" Section in Laravel 5.4 Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) about chaining query conditions (pretty much at the end of the section).